# Pass variable from python file to JS file(node)

Tags: python, node.js

I have a python file and a js file (node js). Now, I want to pass a variable to the js file from python file and after that, I want to execute `$ node file_name.js` on the terminal and save the output in a file/variable

Can someone tell how to do this?

Comment: [python-shell](https://www.npmjs.com/package/python-shell) could help, run a node process and use python-shell to read .py file and pass whatever data you want.

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: After you prepare your .py file and within nodejs, 1- read your .py file 2- expect a message (variable) to be received 3- do whatever you want with the message e.g: use ```fs``` module to write it to a file.  step (1-2) [hint](https://www.npmjs.com/package/python-shell#exchanging-data-between-node-and-python)